# Using arrays of Linux kfifo

Tags: linux, device-driver, can-bus

In **can4linux,** a Linux CAN device character driver currently a proprietary FIFO
implementation is used. The driver supports more then on CAN channel
(MAX_CHANNELS) and each channel can be opened by more than one process
(CAN_MAX_OPEN). If a CAN message is received the message is copied in all the
receive FIFOs for that channel.

Currently it looks like:

```
msg_fifo_t rx_buf[MAX_CHANNELS][CAN_MAX_OPEN];
```

The fifo size and pointers are defined in the msg_fifo_t. rx_buf is therefore a
big two dimensional array of these msg_fifo_t structures.

How can I solve this with using kfifo?
If a user process wants to read from a special
CAN controller and it is the nth process opening for read, I want to get exactly `enter code here`the right fifo (or fifo pointer).

```
ptr = rx_buf[can[x][n];
```

Any links for examples or hints are welcome.